# For loop ends before condition is reached

Tags: python

I am trying to make a number guessing game and the rules is that you get 10 guesses to find the randomly generated number. It will show if your guess is too high/low and if it is correct the program ends. But for some reason, the program ends even though I didn't guess correctly. If someone can troubleshoot my problem it will be appreciated.

```
import random  


rand = random.randint(1,100)  
guesses = 0  

for i in range(10):  
    guess = int(input("Guess the secret number"))  
    if guess > rand:  
        print("your guess is too high")  
        guesses += 1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess < rand:  
        print("your guess is too low")  
        guesses +=1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess == rand:  
        print("you won")  
    break
```

Comment: once I guess the number I want to break the loop and end program

Comment: You only want to break if `guess == rand`; your indentation is off.

Comment: I believe you indented `break` to be inside the last `if` condtion

Comment: @wwii feelsbadman ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`break` will leave the loop directly

```
import random  


rand = random.randint(1,100)  
guesses = 0  

for i in range(10):  
    guess = int(input("Guess the secret number"))  
    if guess > rand:  
        print("your guess is too high")  
        guesses += 1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess < rand:  
        print("your guess is too low")  
        guesses +=1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess == rand:  
        print("you won")
        break # <- move break under the correct if statement
```

Comment: so how will I make it that it will 'break' as soon as the condition is met?

Comment: @J.Doe would be nice if you mark the answer as correct :D

Comment: yeah sure thing it was a big help

Answer (score 0):

`break` statements are used to terminate the current loop. So, when you use this it will end the current loop and the control will be passed to the statement which is after the loop.

In your case, since you have put `break` statement at the end of the `for` loop, so the loop gets terminated in the first iteration.

So, all you can do is put the `break` statement inside the last if condition, like below

```py
import random  


rand = random.randint(1,100)  
guesses = 0  

for i in range(10):  
    guess = int(input("Guess the secret number"))  
    if guess > rand:  
        print("your guess is too high")  
        guesses += 1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess < rand:  
        print("your guess is too low")  
        guesses +=1  
        print("number of guesses",guesses,"/10")  
    if guess == rand:  
        print("you won")  
        break
```